# Is there a way to integrate Django with Next.js?

Tags: django, reactjs, next.js

I've integrated Reactjs with Django by having a function to access `build/index.html`. The below codes show how I do that.

**config/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'search/', react_views.ReactAppView.as_view()),
]
```

**PROJECT_NAME/views.py**

```
class ReactAppView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(str(settings.BASE_DIR), 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html')) as file:
                return HttpResponse(file.read())
        except:
            return HttpResponse(
                """
                Build your React app.
                """,
                status=501,
            )
```

`ReactAppView` function accesses `index.html` which is created with `yarn build` on React side. Basically, I used React just for search view, and other than search view, I used jQuery as it was developed with jQuery first.

Since I found that I need Next.js to use Server Side Rendering (SSR) with React, I've been trying to migrate React app to Next.js. But, Next.js doesn't have `index.html`. It just has `pages/index.js` instead.

I've tried very hard to figure out how to integrate Django with Next.js, but I can't find any helpful resource. Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Run 2 ports on the same server. 1 for django (public facing) and 1 for next.js (internal). Let django handle all web requests. For each request, query SSR from django view to get HTML response. Return that exact HTML response from django view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like you want to serve static files (i.e. React or Next.js bundles).
Django has a guide on how to do this (via `django.contrib.staticfiles`)

The simplest example (straight from the docs) is:

- set the `STATIC_FILES` folder:

  `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
- Put the `index.html` file there and reference it as `/static/index.html`.

For more info on `staticfiles`, please refer to the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

On the Next.js side, you need to either follow the sample at https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export or create manually an `index.html` that includes all next.js bundles that you are using.

Comment: The `index.html` file that I wanna call is from Next.js, not from Django. In React, if you use `yarn build`, it creates index.html in src/build folder, but Next.js doesn't create any index.html file. That's the point that I lost.

Comment: I know how to call static file as I already explained that in the original post, but since there is difference between React and Next, I'm kind of lost there :(

Comment: have you looked into the "Static Exporting" tab in the Next.js homepage?

Comment: @Qerd omg, that was exactly what I was looking for! you made my day! Can you add it as an answer for this question?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late, but Ored's answer is not working with Nextjs.

When using a React SPA, all of the react code will run on the client's browser,  and of course in that case all you need is just serve the React build artifacts as `staticfiles`.

But with Nextjs using SSR, you need to run the Nextjs server (using Nodejs) and you should integrate these 2 servers (Django and Nextjs) to work together.

So, if you are starting a new project you should just use Django as a web service and let Nextjs to be the interface of your application, but if you already have a Django application and want to use Nextjs, check out following article and GitHub repo:

- [Medium: Django + Next.js The Easy Way](https://medium.com/@danialkeimasi/django-next-js-the-easy-way-655efb6d28e1)
- [Github: django-nextjs](https://github.com/QueraTeam/django-nextjs)